# pyspark, group by array specific property through aliases

Tags: python, json, pyspark

i have this structure for my dataframe

```
root: array (nullable = true)
 |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
    |-- time: struct (nullable = true)
        |-- start: string (nullable = true)
        |-- end: string (nullable = true)
    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
        |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
             |-- key: string (nullable = true)
             |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

that i need to transform in this one:

```
 root
     |-- start: string (nullable = true)
     |-- end: string (nullable = true)
     |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- key: string (nullable = true)
     |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

expanding my key-value array on column.

using pivot and groupby i can transform my dataframe:

```
df2 = df.groupby("start","end","id").pivot("prop.key").agg(last("prop.value", True))
```

but i need also to group by one (or more) property(key) value, but i can't.

```
df2 = df.groupby("start","end","id","car_type","car_loc").pivot("prop.key").agg(last("prop.value", True))
```

where "car_type","car_loc" are properties (prop.keys).
i need to  call these properties through their aliases(not using getItem()).
is it possible? anyone can help me please?

thank you

**EDIT**

an example. i have this situation:

```
+---+----------+----------+--------------------+
| id|  start   |    end   |                prop|
+---+----------+----------+--------------------+
|  1|2019-05-12|2020-05-12|[car_type, fiat     |
|  1|2019-05-12|2020-05-12|[car_loc, home      |
|  1|2019-05-12|2020-05-12|[car_num, xd7890    |
|  2|2019-05-13|2020-05-13|[car_type, fiat     |
|  2|2019-05-13|2020-05-13|[car_loc, home      |
|  2|2019-05-13|2020-05-13|[car_num, ae1234    |
|  1|2019-05-12|2020-05-12|[car_type, ford     |
|  1|2019-05-12|2020-05-12|[car_loc, office    |
|  1|2019-05-12|2020-05-12|[car_num, gh7890    |
```

i need to transform dataframe to have the situation :

```
+---------------------+---+--------+-------+-------+
|  start   |    end   | id|car_type|car_loc|car_num|
+---------------------+---+--------+-------+-------+
|2019-05-12|2020-05-12|  1|fiat    |home   |xd7890 |
|2019-05-13|2020-05-13|  2|fiat    |home   |ae1234 |
|2019-05-12|2020-05-12|  1|ford    |office |gh7890 |
```

Comment: explode properties first and just get the columns, i don't know how may values are in the array.

Comment: after the explosion i don't have column's name, and array values number can be variable.                                                                                                                           
    id|           start|             end|                prop|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|  1|2019-05-12T00:00:00|2019-05-12T00:15:00|[car_type, fiat|]

Comment: need sample to do something

Comment: thank you for your answer. i added an example.

Comment: from your original dataframe, use `map_from_entries()` to convert `properties` column into a map and then retrieve 3 keys "car_type","car_loc" and "car_num".